# Redirect to Site Page After Clicking New Button

Tags: sharepoint-online, redirect, newform

Is there a way to redirect to a custom site page after clicking the New button in my library?

[image]

After clicking, should redirect me to a custom page such as:

```
https://<url>/SitePages/Sample.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot achieve your requirement directly.

There is a workaround for the issue, you could customize the new form by PowerApps. And you can customize the new form according to the custom site page.